# iOS dynamic layout (during runtime)

Tags: ios, layout, dynamic, markup

I'm absolutely new to iOS development so any advice would be valuable.

The question itself:
I need to create an application similar to presentation (for sales people). Because 3D window is required existing applications (like Keynote) cannot be used (if you know something that allows loading 3D models - that would be also great).

Of course making it 100% hardcoded is bad idea, because the content of presentation may change. The idea is to use some kind of Msrk-Up language that will allow you to load 'slides' and add content using some config/markup files. By content I mean pictures, text, movies, etc. 3D should be handled

As an example, there is a [Frame control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) in .NET WPF that allows you dynamic loading of HTML, XAML, PDF - we used it to create XAML-based help for the application.

Is there anything like that for iOS?

There is also an idea to provide a predefined set of layouts with possibility to configure content, however that decreases flexibility a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the thing I was looking for is [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).